# How to generate a dump sqlite3 with columns names on insert?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, dump

Regarding the dump generated by sqlite3:

`$ sqlite3 db.sqlite3 .dump > db.dump.txt`

After executing the above command on linux command shell, the dump displays the inserts in the following syntax pattern:

> INSERT INTO "table" VALUES(10,'column0','column1','column2');

But I need the specification of the column names, as in the following example:

> INSERT INTO "table" (id, col_0, col_1, col_2) VALUES(10,'column0','column1','column2');

In the [sqlite3 documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html), I did not find anything specific. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do some kind of search/replace operation after you get the dump. If "table" has the columns "id", "col_0" and "col_1", you would replace "insert into table values" with 'insert into table ("id", "col_0", "col_1") values'.

You can do this in your favorite editor (vim, for example) or in the language of your choice (I'd recommend Python).

The names of the columns could be retrieved from the "create table" lines of the dump file.

Comment: Thanks Otavio :)
I implementededm in Python.